# Migrate Flutter projects

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The following message appeared while I was creating an existing project:

```
Warning: Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your project, add this below lines in `AndroidManifest.xml` after `activity` tag inside `appication` tag:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

**For example my AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example_app">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <application
        android:label="Example App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="false"> 
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<!-- HERE HERE HERE HERE -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```